# ZSH + VIM + CTRL-Z => prompt blocking

Tags: zsh, vim, background-process

I open a vim instance in zsh. Afterwards I move it to the background with `ctrl-z` then again I return to it using `ctrl-z` again and then I close it using `:q` my prompt is blocked and I first have to execute `ctrl-c` or `return/enter` to free it. Is there a way to get a free usable prompt immediately without pressing `ctrl-c` or `return/enter`?

`ctrl-z` key binding in `~/.zshrc`:

```
_zsh_cli_fg() { fg; }
zle -N _zsh_cli_fg
bindkey '^Z' _zsh_cli_fg
```

Comment: Does the same happen if you bring `vim` back to foreground with `fg`, without your function?

Comment: Technically you do have a prompt, and if you type a command it will get executed. A cosmetic problem is that the prompt isn't redisplayed (it now has `[1]  + continued  vim` after it). A much bigger problem is that the terminal mode isn't restored. The tty is in cooked mode, so zsh doesn't detect anything until you press Return or Ctrl+C.

Comment: With “cooked mode”, I guess you mean application/keypad mode (smkx), since “cooked” is the inverse of “raw” (rmkx)?